# Debug stored procedure manually in rapid SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure which check the records first and based on condition it then inserts the records into the table; but I need to validate what records are inserted on what condition so that I will come to know where exactly the changes needs to be done..

Thanks

Comment: OK. What is the question?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm what values are getting inserted and on what condition

Comment: Looks like (a lot of) IF-THEN-ELSEs with additional column in a table which stores info about the condition.

Comment: Yes, lots of insert deletion is happening in that proc but not sure how to debug and on what values and conditions are getting executed

Comment: Aha. Use debugger (if tool you use offers one). Otherwise, put DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE calls into that procedure, enable SERVEROUTPUT and run the procedure. Once it is done, review the output. Alternatively, create a *log* table and insert that (debugging) info into it; include some ID column populated by a sequence and timestamp so that you'd be able to properly sort the result.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but i am new to this so facing the difficulties

Comment: I can tell you how to use the debugger using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) which you tagged, but your question title mentions a different product. Which one do you need help with?

Comment: I just wanted to know how we debug the stored proc and find out the issue and fix it since i am new to this